# Does TFS + VS 2010 support working offline and reconcile intelligently when online?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, merge, checkin

I am using **Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate Ed**. and it is hooked to **TFS Server 2010**. Can I simply do a 'get latest' of my solution, change my working mode to 'work offline' and work at home over the weekend.

When I get back to office I should be able to switch back to 'work online' and TFS should take care of any files I've supposedly checked out and help me **reconcile**. I cannot envisage what files I'll be working on while I'm offline.

Can this be achieved in my setup in a straight forward way?

*Remote access to TFS is ruled out*.

Comment: Note that in TFS 2012, the default is to use the new *local workspace* option, which does not require a connection to the server to check out files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work fine - if Visual Studio can't connect to your TFS server it will switch to offline mode automatically. Upon reconnecting, you can tell it to work online and then check in the files you have changed (either a few at a time per check in or as one whole bundle). It will keep track of which have been edited.

It may inform you when opening the files that they are read-only, but that seems to be linked how it determines which have changed and you can override that per-file as you open them. I'd advise against removing the read-only attribute on any you don't change.

It might be worth simulating it before you rely on it so you understand how it works by disconnecting to your network while still at work.